# Can I terminate Runnable after timeout in JAVA?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, reactive

```java
        ScriptEngineManager scriptEngineMgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine jsEngine = scriptEngineMgr.getEngineByName("nashorn");

        Mono.fromRunnable(() -> {
            System.out.println("11111");
            try {
                System.out.println("2222");
                jsEngine.eval("print(\"hello\");while(1);");
            } catch (ScriptException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("3333");

        }).timeout(Duration.ofMillis(2000)).doOnError(Exception.class, e -> {
            System.out.println("4444");
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }).onErrorResume(Exception.class, e -> {
            System.out.println("5555");
            return Mono.error(e);
        }).block();

        System.out.println("end!!!");
```

This code is never ended up.
And it shows "java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Did not observe any item or terminal signal within 2000ms in 'source(MonoRunnable)' (and no fallback has been configured)
".

I want to terminate it in 2 seconds and then see "end!!!".

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a rather odd use of reactor - if you really want to timeout after 2 seconds, then a more normal / better approach might be to spawn your `eval()` in a new thread, and `interrupt()` that thread after a certain time (then dealing with the `InterruptedException` as appropriate.)

However, to answer the question directly, your `onErrorResume()` call at the end of the chain is itself returning an `Mono.error` (essentially a clone of the same erroneous `Mono` it's dealing with.) When you call `block()`, [this exception is then thrown](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#block--).

Instead, you probably want to return `Mono.empty()` rather than `Mono.error(e)` in that `onErrorResume()` block.

Comment: @Berry Impressive answers.. seen you very frequent & quick with answers for reactive/webflux. Can you suggest some good source to study the same . Thanks !

Comment: @AdityaRewari No beating the reactor reference doc to get started :-) https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/

Comment: Thanks very much for your comment. I solved it like your help

Answer (score 0):

I sovled like this. But I'm not sure this is a good way. 
I'm waiting for any better idea.

```java
        ScriptEngineManager scriptEngineMgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine jsEngine = scriptEngineMgr.getEngineByName("nashorn");

        String script = "$result.test = 1;\nwhile(1);";
        Thread th = new Thread(() -> {
            jsEngine.put("$result", new JSONObject());
            try {
                jsEngine.eval(script);
            } catch (ScriptException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        Mono.defer(() -> {
            th.start();
            try {
                th.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            return Mono.just(true);
        }).timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(2)).doOnError(TimeoutException.class, e -> {
            // e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(th.isAlive());
            th.stop();
        }).doAfterTerminate(() -> {
            System.out.println(result);
            System.out.println("end!!!");
            System.out.println(th.isAlive());
        }).onErrorReturn(false).block();
```